# Unable to show the data in the proper sequence

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a function that executes based on a condition and if the condition is true then it creates a new component dynamically using component-factory.

> in my case a text component

- This is of the function that I want to execute

  ```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
   if (this.editStatus == true) {
     this.QDS.setEditMode(true);

     this.map.forEach((value) => {

       console.log('Before checking...', value);

       if (typeof value == 'string') {

         // checks if the value is HTML
         if (this.isHtml(value)) {
           console.log('After checking', value);

           // storing this value in a service which has to be passed to the created component
           this.QDS.setPassingDataText(value);

           // function to create a new component
           this.openContainer('textcontainer');
         }
         else if (this.isImage(value)) {
           console.log('After checking', value);
           this.openContainer('cameracontainer');
         }
       }
       else if (typeof value == 'object') {
         console.log('After checking', value);
         this.openContainer('documentcontainer');
       }

     })
    }
  };
  ```
- This function creates the component:

  ```
  openContainer(typeOfC: string) {
   if (typeOfC === 'textcontainer') {

     const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynatextComponent);
     const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
     componentRef.instance._ref = componentRef;

     // this is a component ref for my use
     let count = this.QDS.getGlobalCounter();
     count = count + 1;
     this.QDS.setGlobalCounter(count);

   }
  }
  ```
- The dynamic.component.ts file of the of the created component

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentSub = this.qc.allcomponent.subscribe(components => {
      this.loadedData = components;
    });

    // this.editorForm = new FormGroup({
    //   'editor': new FormControl(null)
    // });

    this.counter = this.QDS.getGlobalCounter();
    this.editModeStatus = this.QDS.getEditMode();

    if (this.editModeStatus == true) {

      this.data = this.QDS.getPassingdDataText();
      console.log('Dyna Text', this.data);

      this.editorForm = this.fb.group({
        editor: this.data
      })

    } else {
      console.log('Not in Edit-Mode');
    }

    this.editCheck = true;
    console.log('ref', this.counter);
  }
  ```

**Console Output**

[image: console Output]

The problem is that the condition that I want to run executes properly but the data that has to be passed to the Dynamically created Component isn't in the proper sequence.

**What should actually happen is:**

```
 Before checking <p>data1</p>
 After checking <p>data1</p>
 Dyna Text <p>data1</p>
 ref 1
```

and so on for data 2...

**ref 1 (this is a counter variable which tells how many time a component is created)**

But what happens is that it checks the conditions, executes the inner if's and then creates the component but saves the last value which is data 2, which instead has to be data 1 and the next one as data 2

**output of the excuted**
[image: UI Output]

This is my environment:

> Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.1
> @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.1
> @angular/cli                  : 11.2.1
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0

Comment: Can you paste code instead of these images?

Comment: Changed the question content with code where ever possible

Comment: So, just to make things clear you want the for loop things to be executed in the sequence? Currently, they are just executing randomly.

Comment: It is executing in sequence but since its happening fast the variable that needs to stored for the data to be passed is being overwritten. 
And also maybe execute the loop in the proper sequence. 

sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this. I have made the forEach loop to wait for the component to render and do its things , and it will wait for all the components which will be created by the for loop. The promise will be only resolved once the execution for the component is being completed.

Promise will make sure that once the component is being done with things then it should tell the for loop to keep moving on.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 if (this.editStatus == true) {
   this.QDS.setEditMode(true);

   this.map.forEach( async (value) => { //
   for (let [key, value] of this.map) {

     console.log('Before checking...', value);

     if (typeof value == 'string') {

       // checks if the value is HTML
       if (this.isHtml(value)) {
         console.log('After checking', value);

         // storing this value in a service which has to be passed to the created component
         this.QDS.setPassingDataText(value);

         // function to create a new component
        await this.openContainer('textcontainer');
       }
       else if (this.isImage(value)) {
         console.log('After checking', value);
         await this.openContainer('cameracontainer');
       }
     }
     else if (typeof value == 'object') {
       console.log('After checking', value);
       await this.openContainer('documentcontainer');
     }

  }
};
```

```
openContainer(typeOfC: string) {

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    if (typeOfC === 'textcontainer') {
 
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynatextComponent);
      const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
      componentRef.instance._ref = componentRef;
   
      // this is a component ref for my use
      let count = this.QDS.getGlobalCounter();
      count = count + 1;
      this.QDS.setGlobalCounter(count);
      res('true');
    }
  })
 }
```

I am attaching a [link](https://medium.com/dailyjs/the-pitfalls-of-async-await-in-array-loops-cf9cf713bfeb) which can help you to understand how it can work for more details.

Comment: I have made changes to the code according to what you have added but still facing the same issue which is, only the last data that the loop runs is filling those text boxes.
It runs in sequence.

The for-loop on ngAfterViewInit doesn't work as intended as it runs the loop *2 based on the no of times the inner loop ran meaning if i had to print 2 times values it would print 4 times.

I logged the value that the component should receive it does not receive the first value only the second value gets printed.
i also tried to set the value as a behavior subject but it did not make difference.